# Automagically build an array from ListView sub-items

Tags: c#, lambda, .net-4.0

I'm populating a `ListView.Items` by calling:

```
for(...)
{
  view.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new [] { nickname, fullname } ));
}
```

I'd later on like to get a `string[]` of all the `fullname` values. Obviously this is trivial to do in normal C-style code with a for-loop but I wondered if C# language features allow this do be done more neatly using lambdas and so on?

Answer (score 2):

Since items are added by order. second SubItem is `fullname`

```
string[] fullnames = view.Items.OfType<ListViewItem>().Select(x => x.SubItems[1].Text).ToArray();
```

Note that type of `x.SubItems[1]` is `ListViewSubItem`. use the property `Text` to get its string value.

You can also use Anonymous type to get both nickname and fullname.

```
var allnames =
    listView1.Items.OfType<ListViewItem>()
        .Select(x => new {NickName = x.SubItems[0], FullName = x.SubItems[1]})
        .ToArray();

// usage

foreach(var n in allnames)
{
     string nickname = n.NickName;
     string fullname = n.FullName;
}
```

Comment: Gotta love C#, really.